# vb.net Image and BorderStyle is not a member of 'WindowsApplication.PictureBox'

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I met the following errors in my vb.net project:

(1)  Image is not a member of 'WindowsApplication.PictureBox'

(2)  BorderStyle is not a member of 'WindowsApplication.PictureBox'

The following is my code:

```
Dim NewPicBox As New PictureBox

    NewPicBox.Visible = True
    NewPicBox.Width = 1200
    NewPicBox.Height = 1200
    NewPicBox.Top = 0
    NewPicBox.Left = 0
    NewPicBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    NewPicBox.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\11.gif")

    Me.Controls.Add(NewPicBox)
```

I have already imports system.drawing in it. Tried to searching from internet, even cannot find the similar issue. I am using .net Framework 3.5.

Can anybody help me? thanks.

Comment: What framework are you using. Winforms , WPF ?

Comment: Hi Mark, it is windows forms. thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you have another PictureBox class declared, your code works for me in a new project with no problems. It should be System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox not WindowsApplication.PictureBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the error messages says `WindowsApplication.PictureBox` means that you have defined a type or namespace in your project named `PictureBox` and the compiler is inetrpreting your code as referring to that rather than the `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox` class.  You should generally avoid such name clashes if possible but, if you must use the same name as an existing type, you must then qualify the name of that existing type when you use it in code, i.e. instead of:

```
Dim NewPicBox As New PictureBox
```

use:

```
Dim NewPicBox As New Windows.Forms.PictureBox
```

In this case though, I very much doubt that using `PictureBox` as the name of one of your own types is appropriate.  I suggest that you change it and then the code you have will work.